# What does the notation $f(x-0) $ or $f(x+0)$ mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

I'm studying a book by JL Lions. In it he uses this notation, what can it mean?

An example context is

> $f$ has a jump point at $x$ with $k(x+0) > k(x-0)$

In this case, I believe it means $k(x+\epsilon) > k(x-\epsilon)$ for positive $\epsilon$, but why not just use that?

Another example:

> $\beta$ can be considered as a multivalued function if $\beta(x) \in [\beta(x-0), \beta(x-0) + b]$

..what neighborhoods around $\beta(x)$ are we taking here?

Comment: I've never seen that notation but based on context it seems to mean $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}k(x)>\lim_{x\to\ 0^-}k(x)$$

Comment: Thanks @D.Clark, that is what I thought. Can you have a look at the second example I've put up please.

Comment: While agreeing with D. Clark on th einterpretation, I must say that this notatin is dangerously misleading for anybody knowing that $x+0=x-0=x$ even before we plug these values into $k$ or $\beta$.

Comment: For the second, it reads the value of $\beta(x)$ is contained in the interval $[\lim_{x\to 0^-}\beta(x),\lim_{x\to 0^-}\beta(x)+b]$. So, your function could have a discontinuity at $x$ where $\beta(x)$ does not equal the limit as $x \to 0$ from the left.

Comment: @D.Clark The meaning of the notation is $$f(x+0)=\lim_{t\to x^+} f(t)$$ and not the limit at $0^+$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $f(x+0)$ or shortly $f(x+)$ is used for $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to x^+}f(t)$ and the same thing for $f(x-0)$ or $f(x-)$. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions) for an example of use.